# Giving iPhone app root permissions

Tags: iphone, ios4, permissions, root

I am trying to give my iPhone app root permissions from inside the app itself when I launch it, it will run on a jailbroken device also. Could anyone explain how I might do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, are you ***really really sure*** that your app actually needs root? root is ***very*** dangerous if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

That said, to run as root, install your app into `/Applications/` then `setuid` the executable to root.

If you can, separate out the code that needs root privileges into a separate `setuid`'d executable and shell out to that from your main application (which would run as mobile). This lets you isolate the privileged code to make securing it easier.